# Explode array to make two variables so I can get info from database table to send email

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, web

Right, so I have an array in one table in my database. I need to break this array apart so I can use one bit of it to get information from another table in my database and then send an email with that information in.

My array in the table looks like this

30-1,

30 is the product ID and 1 is the quantity. (Quantity of item purchased)

Have I been a muppet and got this wrong?

```
//Get product_id_array of item purchased
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product_id_array FROM transactions WHERE id='$orderID'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $prod_quant_array = $row['product_id_array'];
}
//Explode prod_quant_array
(explode("-", $prod_quant_array));
$product_id = $prod_quant_array[0];
$product_quantity = $prod_quant_array[1];
```

I thought that this would then give me two variables. 
`$product_id` would be 30 and `$product_quantity` would 1

I'm then trying to use this information to get more information from another table.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products WHERE id='$product_id'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    $product_price = $row['product_price'];
}
```

As you can see, my WHERE is looking at the $product_id variable. 
So when I try and send the email, I get the email, but I can't see the `$product_name` or `$product_price`. Please ignore those other variables, they are displaying fine in the email and are coming from a different query.

```
/////// Send Email ///////
$to = "" . $payer_email . "";
$subject = "Confirmation of your order";
$message .= "Dear " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . ",

This is an email to confirm your recent purchase of goods with Bloodlust.

You have ordered: 

--------------------------------------------------
" . $product_name . ".

" . $product_price . "
--------------------------------------------------

Please keep this email for your records.

Please note that this is not a proof of transaction.

Thank you.";
$from = "no-reply@blood-lust.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Is my explode() ?
Or is it something else?

This is absolutely killing my brain, I've been at it for hours. Please help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$prod_quant_array = explode("-", $prod_quant_array);`

And as a side note you should really normalize your database by adding a quantity field and have the current field only hold the product id. That way you can also join the product price in the same query, rather than sending another one.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you so much. This fixed it! Also, thanks for the tip. I will get that done. I'll accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand explode()

You need to assign the explode to a variable, that variable will then take on an array of values that explode creates......

Instead of:

```
(explode("-", $prod_quant_array));
$product_id = $prod_quant_array[0];
$product_quantity = $prod_quant_array[1];
```

Do:

```
$theArray = (explode("-", $prod_quant_array));
$product_id = $theArray[0];
$product_quantity = $theArray[1];
```

Comment: Sorry @George, dont mistake me with my reply below. I was writing and didnt see your reply.

Comment: Thank you George, Clarence answered quicker so I'll accept that one  but I acknowledge that yours is the same, so thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You have an error. Change the lines

```
(explode("-", $prod_quant_array));
$product_id = $prod_quant_array[0];
$product_quantity = $prod_quant_array[1];
```

To

```
$prod_quant_array = explode("-", $prod_quant_array);
$product_id = $prod_quant_array[0];
$product_quantity = $prod_quant_array[1];
```

Comment: Thank you, Clarence beat you to it so I'll will accept that answer but I acknowledge that yours is the same, so thanks :D

Comment: Sure. Glad that SO came to rescue. Cheers.